# Transferring saved data connections between Visual Studio installations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, connection-string, database-connection, schema-compare

I use the data and schema comparison tools in Visual Studio a great deal.  I just finished installing VS 2010 on a new VM and realized, of course, that all the saved data connections from my previous installation are not available.  Is there a way to transfer these connections between installations of VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just copy the file from

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\
Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView`

from the installation with the data connections to the same location in the VM.