# How can I export the saved Data Connections in Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 and import them into 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I use Visual Studio 2005, 2008, and 2010 for various projects. Is there any way to export the saved Data Connections that I have in the Server Explorer pane on one version, and import them into the other versions?

I took a look at the Import and Export Settings Wizard, and it has a section for Database Tools, but there's no mention of the saved connections.

Comment: I did come across this question, but it's only referring to different instances of 2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173406/transferring-saved-data-connections-between-visual-studio-installations

Comment: Yeah, it would be helpful to know for all versions. I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 3):

I found a text based file that contains my connections: C:\Documents and Settings\Your Profile name goes here\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView

I don't know how well it ports into the next version but it's a start. At least his has the text based names of your servers.

Comment: Nice, that's a step in the right direction. Unfortunately it looks like the rest of the Connection String is encrypted.